# What do E and COM mean in a blower motor wiring diagram?

Tags: electrical, wiring, blower, motor

I'm a bit confused with the wiring diagram of this blower motor. Is the COM the neutral wire or the hot wire? And then would the E be neutral if the COM was the hot wire? Or is it the ground?

I thought that since this was a variable speed motor (or so I thought) the wires (speed 1 - 4) all ran current at different levels to control the speed of the motor, then COM would be neutral. So would that mean E was ground?

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Comment: I've found a number of diagrams with all the wires except the grey "E" wire.  While guessing is a bad thing to do, my guess is that "E" stands for "Enable", i.e., a way to turn the fans off with a single line.

Answer (score 9):

Probably, yes: COM usually stands for common, meaning neutral. E usually stands for Earth, meaning ground.

Comment: And the hot wire is connected to **one** of the 4 speeds (at any given time) in order to produce that speed (returning/completing the circuit on neutral/com.) Typically by a control board, or a 1-in-4-out "break before make" switch

Comment: Interesting that something that claims that it `Conforms to UL Std. No. 507` would use "COM" and "E" instead of "Neutral" and "Ground". UL is US-based and COM & Earth are not common terms in the US. Of course, it could be manufactured elsewhere in the world by a non-US based company and that may have been there and was simply approved by UL. Still... a little odd.

Comment: Also interesting that there's (crudely printed, so not as clear as they might be) ground symbols that are not explicitly connected to the E - so E *could* be something other than Earth/Ground. Get out the ohmmeter...

Comment: I always assumed ground was represented as G or with the symbol. First time seeing E being used. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4):

I was assuming this was an HVAC blower, but this is actually a remote blower module for a range hood.

Installation instructions located here: [Zline T95 Dual Remote Blower](https://assets.ajmadison.com/ajmadison/itemdocs/Remote_Blower_Installation_43.pdf)

The unit appears to be powered remotely from the range hood, where the control board and buttons are.  It also appears to supply the cable.  In this case, I would definitely assume E means protective earth in the diagram.